# My code is inserting two characters instead of one in textViewDidChangeSelection

Tags: swift, text, char

I have a textView where if I select a character and that character is a ballot box (\u{2610}) then the code should replace the ballot box with a ballot box with x char (\u{2612}).

The problem is the code is inserting two ballot box with x chars (\u{2612}) instead of one.

I am using the `textViewDidChangeSelection` method to do the replacement. I have included the code below.

Any idea why 2 characters are being inserted instead of one? Is the method being inadvertently called upon itself?

Extensive debugging shows that the ViewDidChange method seems to be running a couple times.

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    //make sure there's a range
    if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
        //get and print cursor pos for debugging
        let cursorPos = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)
        print("cursor position on ViewDidChangeSelection:", "\(cursorPos)")

        // grab one char to right of selection to check for ballot
        if let newPosition = textView.position(from: range.start, offset: +1) {
            if let startPosition = textView.position(from: range.start, offset: 0) {
                let range2 = textView.textRange(from: startPosition , to: newPosition)
                let selectedText2 = textView.text(in: range2!)
                print("selected text is:", "\(selectedText2!)")

                if selectedText2 == "\u{2610}" {
                    //select the ballot symbol and replace
                    textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: startPosition, to: newPosition)
                    textView.insertText("\u{2612}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results should be that the character u{2610} should be replaced with u{2612} one time. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `textView.selectedTextRange` also triggers the `textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView)` event, so the method is called twice.

If you need to change only one character, you could replace like this:

```
if selectedText2 == "\u{2610}" {
   //select the ballot symbol and replace
   let range = textView.textRange(from: startPosition, to: newPosition)
   textView.replace(range!, withText:"\u{2612}")
}
```

If you need to change all the occurrences, you could do the replace like this:

```
if selectedText2 == "\u{2610}" {
     //select the ballot symbol and replace
     textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2610}", with: "\u{2612}")
}
```